# Написание приставки к фамилии со строчной буквы в начале предложения

Tags: прописная-строчная

Как правильно написать имя с западноевропейской фамилией с приставкой **T. J. van Been**?
Для оформления списка литературы требуется написать сначала фамилию, а ее приставка пишется со строчной буквы. Но с другой стороны, это начало предложения (после точки).

Варианты:

1. van Been, T. J.
2. Van Been, T. J.

Answer (score 1):

Been, T.J. van

У Ван Гога тоже было van в имени. Vincent van Gogh.

Gogh, Vincent van - в "Британнике" написано так.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе Milanga Mirael предлагает выход вполне действенный - а, главное, в некотором смысле узаконенный. Действительно, это голландское "van" (аналог немецкого von) в библиографии и подобных случаях выносится и отделяется от фамилии. Я только хотел бы добавить, что английские правила в целом не стоит переносить на русскую почву, тем более, что устоявшихся передача известных фамилий может отличаться от обычной практики.

Но если смотреть на вопрос шире, то так. Когда вы передаете в оригинальном написании иноязычное имя собственное, то надо придерживаться орфографии первоисточника. В голландском предложение может начинаться не только со строчной буквы, но и с апострофа - это особенность написания некоторых имен собственных. Так что если надо написать именно "van Been" после точки (безотносительно к построению списка), то заглавная тут неуместна. Так что тут проблем нет. Правда, проблемы могут возникнуть при составлении списков с фамилиями из диалектов вариантов голландского - в африкаанс, например, "van" пишется с заглавной... Но это уже другого плана проблемы.